# Finding specific numbers in a string and assigning a value

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops, contains

I have a column containing unique employee ID's, where the unique numerical value (usually at the end of the ID) accounts for their location.

for example:

```
EmployeeID  
ABC-10  
DEF-70  
GHI-20  
BCD-70
```

...

where 10 = New York, 20 = Paris, 70 = London

I'd like to create a loop/piece of code which scans the EmployeeID for a value and then assigns a corresponding column with the Location. I've tried the below:

`df.loc[df['EmployeeID'].contains("10"), 'Location'] == 'New York'`

However I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

I'm hoping to achieve the following:

```
EmployeeID       Location 
 
ABC-10           New York <br>
DEF-70           London <br>
GHI-20           Paris <br>
BCD-70           London <br>
```

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = ["ABC-10","DEF-70","GHI-20","BCD-70"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["EmployeeID"])    

dict1 = {10: "New York", 70:"London", 20:"Paris"}

print(dict1)

def get_id(text):
    id=int(text.split("-")[-1])
    return dict1[id]   

df['Locations'] = df["EmployeeID"].apply(get_id)

print (df)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If this question was formatted properly, the website wouldn't have let you post your answer as it is 100% code without any explaination. Could you provide an explanation to your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because `df` is defined as a string, not a DataFrame, and thus, a string does not have the attribute `loc`. Please check your definition of `df` again.

You just need to re-define `df` correctly, and repeat the same logic for each of the city names, and your code should work.

```
df.loc[df['EmployeeID'].contains("10"), 'Location'] == 'New York'
df.loc[df['EmployeeID'].contains("20"), 'Location'] == 'Paris'
df.loc[df['EmployeeID'].contains("70"), 'Location'] == 'London'
```

Comment: I've sorted the problem now and have instead used df.series.str.contains('10') which works fine in order to gain a true/false result. However, is there a way to return a new column with the location in? Many thanks